# Go text/template: how to convert bool to int 0/1?

Tags: go, go-templates

With Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language, how can I convert a bool to an int (false=0, true=1)?

Here is an example using my own [goproc](https://github.com/dolmen-go/goproc) tool that allows to execute template from the command line:

```
$ echo false | goproc -e '{{.}} => <template here>'
false => 0
$ echo true | goproc -e '{{.}} => <template here>'
true => 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the simplest:

```
digitizeBoolTemplate := "{{if . }}1{{else}}0{{end}}"
```

https://goplay.tools/snippet/T6EwkKLNmhG

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack: use the `index` built-in function to extract byte values from a specially crafted string that contains bytes 0 and 1 respectively at positions 5 and 4. The lengths of strings `"true"`/`"false"` are used as the index value.

```
$ echo false | goproc -e '{{.}} => {{index "....\001\000" (len (print .))}}{{"\n"}}'
false => 0
$ echo true | goproc -e '{{.}} => {{index "....\001\000" (len (print .))}}{{"\n"}}'
true => 1
```